# Monitoring Tools for Play Framework Application

Tags: java, scala, playframework, jvm

What are some existing tools for monitoring Play Framework Application?

Of course JVisualVM may be used, but I mean special tools for a Play Application.

**2.4 or higher**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are a few that might be helpful,

1. [New relic](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/production-monitoring-for-play-framework-with-new-relic)
2. [Ostrich](https://github.com/twitter/ostrich)(from Twitter for all sort of scala application)
3. Lightbends Reactive Monitoring tool, [Intelligent Monitoring (OpsClarity)](https://www.lightbend.com/products/monitoring)
4. [Metric-play](https://github.com/kenshoo/metrics-play)
5. [Kamon](http://kamon.io/documentation/get-started/)